# How can I make the background of a grid fill from top to bottom?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid area and I would like for that to be filled from top to bottom with the background green color:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="72*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Here is Row 2

```xml
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE">
            <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  BackgroundColor="Lime"/>     
        </Grid>
```

What I get with this code is a white area that's the correct size of the grid but there's just a small green line in the middle.

How can I make the grid fill completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to set Background attribute of tag "Grid" to your color of choice.

```
<Grid x:Name="phraseGrid" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="72*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="buttonGrid" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE">
        <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ButtonGridVisible, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} }" Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Lime">     
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AbsoluteLayout as a root. 
And put your background grid first on the AbsoluteLayout with full width and height. 
Then add your content on the same AbsoluteLayout as well.